# SQLite Trigger does not work1

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I am trying to use trigger to insert a vlaue. I have 2 tables are connected togather Question and Paper. 
Question has these columns (question_id primary key, correct_answer varchar) and I have inserted the values

insert into question values (1,"B")

Paper has these columns (Question_id foreign key , student_answer varchare,score integer)

the trigger should work afetr insert into  paper if student_answer equal correct_answer then insert into score 1 else 0

this is my code for the trigger

```
      create trigger if not exists insert_score after insert on paper
      for each row
      when (select * from paper,question 
            where question.question_id = paper.question_id 
            and question.correct_Answer = paper.student_Answer)
      begin 
            insert into paper (Score) values (1);
            end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874538/trigger-does-not-work)

Comment: Please don't delete your question and ask the same in another. Improve your old question.

Comment: this error shows when I insert into paper table: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS set_score
AFTER INSERT ON paper
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.score IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE paper
    SET Score = EXISTS (SELECT *
                        FROM question
                        WHERE question_id = NEW.question_id
                          AND correct_Answer = NEW.student_Answer)
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```